# convert dictionary with metadata to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

i Have a dictionary like below, looking to convert it as a dataframe with its all data.

{'content': 'hello i'm from london',
'meta': {'name': 'smith)',
'q_id': 001,
'c_id': '002'}}

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
d = {'content': 'hello im from london',
     'meta': {'name': 'smith)', 'q_id': '001', 'c_id': '002'}}
              
df = pd.json_normalize(d)                                              
print (df)
    
                content meta.name meta.q_id meta.c_id
0  hello im from london    smith)       001       002
```